# How to check if two dates not on the same calendar day

Tags: javascript, date

How to check if two dates not on the same day. I came up with this solution but maybe there is a better way to do this:

```
 var actualDate = new Date();
 var isNotToday = dateToCheck.getDay() !== actualDate.getDay() || dateToCheck < actualDate - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Comment: Did you try to output the result of `dateToCheck.getDay()` and `actualDate.getDay()` to see if there's anything wrong?

Comment: What if `dateToCheck` were exactly one week later than today?

Comment: @lc., thats why I've checked if a minimum of 24 hours had passed.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Maybe I'm missing something (it is late), but if for `dateToCheck` were one week later than today, the `.getDay()`s would be equal and `dateToCheck` would be much greater than `actualDate - 24h`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if two Dates have the same date info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428327/checking-if-two-dates-have-the-same-date-info)

Comment: @KyleMit That question is somewhat confusing as a duplicate-target, since the question is written somewhat vaguely and the top answer clearly interpreted it to mean something different from what's being asked here in this question.

Comment: Just to be clear, this question was asked way before the other, so how can this be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @KyleStrand, perhaps. In both questions, the answer set is largely the same and I was just going with the newer one as a dupe.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle, unless I'm reading this wrong, this Q was asked in 2012, the other was in 2010.  I don't think being a duplicate is bad in anyway, just that people looking for canonical answers can all get funneled to the same resource.

Comment: Even if this were the older question, older questions are still sometimes closed as "duplicates" if the newer question is clearer or has better answers.

Comment: @KyleMit Do you agree that the other question, as it stands, is less clear and has a less-helpful accepted answer? If so, possibly we should reverse the direction of the dupe-arrow.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Another option is using `.toDateString()` function to parse both dates into strings. The function formats output to: "Wed Jul 28 1993." Then you can compare both date strings.

```
actualDate.toDateString() === dateToCheck.toDateString()
// returns true if actualDate is same day as dateToCheck
```

Here's a Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/J5Dyn78TdDUzX82T0ypA

And more from MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString

Comment: Now that's using your head!

Comment: Guess this is the easiest one-liner answer!

Answer (score 22):

How about checking for the same day, month & year:

```
var isSameDay = (dateToCheck.getDate() == actualDate.getDate() 
        && dateToCheck.getMonth() == actualDate.getMonth()
        && dateToCheck.getFullYear() == actualDate.getFullYear())
```

Comment: this method seems to be the fastest: https://jsperf.com/check-same-date

Comment: I would use this for multiple operations, otherwise the accepted answer is a bit cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

It would be safest to check day, month and year:

```
var isNotToday = dateToCheck.getDate() != actualDate.getDate()
      || dateToCheck.getMonth() != actualDate.getMonth()
      || dateToCheck.getFullYear() != actualDate.getFullYear();
```

This will ensure you don't get oddities when it comes to DST and leap years which could interfere otherwise.

Comment: I think he want to check if both date are monday, tuesday, wednesday, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getStartOfDay(aDate){
    //returns the very beginning of the same day
    return new Date(aDate.getTime() - aDate.getTime() % 86400000);
}

var aDate1 = getStartOfDay(new Date());
var aDate2 = getStartOfDay(new Date(1981, 7, 3));

var result = aDate1.getTime() === aDate2.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the date object with a time so they're both generated at midnight.  Then just check the epoch time.

```
new Date('11/12/2012').getTime() === new Date('11/11/2012').getTime()
> false
new Date('11/12/2012').getTime() === new Date('11/12/2012').getTime()
> true
new Date('November 12, 2012').getTime() === new Date('11/12/2012').getTime()
> true
new Date('12 November, 2012').getTime() === new Date('11/12/2012').getTime()
> true
```

The dates just need to be parseable by the `Date` object (I'm on chrome 23.0.1271.17 (Official Build 159779) beta) and if you don't pass a time they'll generate at midnight.

If you're getting a time, just drop it on the floor and test against midnight.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isEqual(startDate, endDate) {
    return endDate.valueOf() == startDate.valueOf();
}

var now =new Date();
var startDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var endDate = new Date(2017, 0, 13)

var result = isEqual(startDate , endDate);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `startOf` method for instances of `Date`:

```
dateA.startOf('day').getTime() === dateB.startOf('day').getTime()
```

Here's the method:

```
Date.prototype.startOf = function(unit) {
    var clone = new Date(this.getTime()), day;
    /* */if (unit === 'second') clone.setMilliseconds(0);
    else if (unit === 'minute') clone.setSeconds(0,0);
    else if (unit === 'hour'  ) clone.setMinutes(0,0,0);
    else {
        clone.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        if (unit === 'week') {
            day = clone.getDay();
            clone = day ? new Date(clone - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * day) : clone;
        }
        else if (unit === 'month') clone.setDate(1);
        else if (unit === 'year' ) clone.setMonth(0,1);
    }
    return clone;
};
```