# PHP check if two Datetimes are not on the same calendar day

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have two Datetimes like this (the dates being actually $vars)

```
$startTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i', '2015/01/01 23:00');
$endTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i', '2015/01/02 01:00');
```

I struggle with a (possibly pretty) simple problem: How could I determine if the two dates are on different calendar days?

I cannot do `<` as `2015/01/01 22:00 < 2015/01/01 23:00` would also be true. I can also not do this:

```
$diff = $startTime->diff($endTime);
$days = $diff->format('%d');

echo $days;
```

as it gives me `0`.

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802722/how-to-check-if-two-dates-not-on-the-same-calendar-day) gives me an idea about how to do it, but for javascript, what would be the equivalent for php?

//UPDATE

```
    $startDate = $startTime->format('Y/m/d');
    $endDate = $endTime->format('Y/m/d');
    $diffDates = $startDate->diff($endDate);
    $daysDiff = $diffDates->format('%d');

    echo $daysDiff;
```

I think that might be the right approach now, thanks to the comments, but now I get `Error: Call to a member function diff() on string`

//UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO

I just want to have the difference in days, so for the above it would be `'1'` (although only 2 hours difference actually) and for example `'2015/01/01 23:00' and '2015/01/03 17:00'` would be `'2'`.

Comment: Why don't you just format them using something like `Y-m-d` and compare them?

Comment: what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I want that the above example gives 1 as a result, as it means there is one day between those Datetimes

Comment: `$isSameCalendarDay = $d1->format('Y-m-d') === $d2->format('Y-m-d')`?

Comment: You need to use `diff()` on `DateTime` objects, not the strings that result from `format()`.

Comment: Are you trying to also calculate the difference **with the same code**? That doesn't make any sense, two dates can differ on 1 hour and belong to the same day or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the dates with time set to 00:00:00:

```
$startTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i:s', '2015/01/01 00:00:00');
$endTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i:s', '2015/01/02 00:00:00');
```

or reset time to zero on existing dates:

```
$startTime->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$endTime->setTime(0, 0, 0);
```

then it should work:

```
$diff = $startTime->diff($endTime);
$days = $diff->format('%d');

echo $days; // 1
```

**Bonus**

If you want to work only with dates, remember to set the time to 00:00:00 in `createFromFormat` or reset it with `setTime`. If you won't provide time in `createFromFormat` PHP will set it to the current time:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-01-21');
print $date->format('H:i:s'); //not 00:00:00
```

To fix it, you must either:

- provide 00:00:00 time in format:

  `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-01-21 00:00:00');`
- prefix the date format with exclamation mark and omit the time, this will set the time to 00:00:00 automatically:

  `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', '2016-01-21');`
- reset the time after creation:

  `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-01-21');
   $date->setTime(0, 0);`

Comment: `setTime` was what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that calculated diff is not real since we aren't using original times any more.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is one of the few situations where the use of strings for date calculations is justified:

```
function onDifferentDays(\DateTimeInterface $startTime, \DateTimeInterface $endTime){
    return $startTime->format('Y-m-d')!==$endTime->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

This code should be easy to extend to include time zone.

There're other alternatives but I don't think they're normally worth the effort:

1. Compare element by element (day, month and year):

   - The PHP `DateTime` class doesn't offer dedicated functions, only `format()`.
2. Normalize both dates to a common time and compare with `==` (not `===`):

   - Unless you're using immutable objects you need to clone input or expect side effects
   - You also need to ensure that time exists in the active time zone though midnight is probably safe enough.

Whatever, YMMV ;-)

Comment: This is almost what I was looking for, but instead of true/false, I need the number of days, so 2015/01/01 08:00 and 2015/01/03 17:00 would output 2. But I think that I can figure that out myself, so thank you so far!

Comment: Well, I don't know what you need but this is what you've actually asked :-?

Answer (score 2):

Comparing formatted dates is the right thing to do:

```
$a->format('Y-m-d') === $b->format('Y-m-d')
```

There is a method for that if you use Carbon:

```
$dt1->isSameDay($dt2)
```

So I recommend to use it instead of previous answers given here.

http://carbondoc/docs/#api-comparison

Comment: Could you link the documentation of that method? I was not able to find it.

Comment: Comparison section `$dt->isSameDay($dt2); // Same day of same month of same year`

Comment: It's an old answer, I think there were a "Carbon" tag in the question previously, but not sure.