# Unable to get some info in a subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get a value in my mongoDB collection. I would like to get the title of a movie and the sales (nbSold) of this movie for the current month.

Here is how my data are stored :

```
"_id" : ObjectId("52e6a1aacf0b3b522a8a157a"),
"title" : "Pulp Fiction",
"sales" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-11-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "nbSold" : 6
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "nbSold" : 2
        }
    ]
```

I'm using mongoose and this is how I build my query for the december of 2013 :

```
var query = Movie.find({"title":"Pulp Fiction"}, "title sales.nbSold")
                 .where("sales.date")
                 .equals(new Date("2013-12-01"));
```

However, this is the output that I am receiving :

```
{ title: 'Pulp Fiction', sales: [ { nbSold: 6 }, { nbSold: 2 } ] }
```

I would like to have only the title associated with the nbSold of the current month (2 in my case). What is the correct way to do this ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should close your `where` call. You should call `.exec(callback)` when you're done comparing, and you should be using `select` instead of equals along with `$elemMatch`. Try this:

```
var query = Movie.find({"title":"Pulp Fiction"}, "title sales.nbSold")
                 .where("sales.date")
                 .select({ sales: { $elemMatch: new Date("2013-12-01") }})
                 .exec(function(err, doc) {
                     return console.dir(doc);
                 });
```

You should also have a callback. **I ran this on my machine, and it definitely works.** I posted code earlier that wasn't quite right, but this does the trick. [See the documentation for an example.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

Also, I'd be concerned as to how you're seeing if the date matches. If the time is off in your `Date` object but the date matches, Mongo won't find a match. And I don't know exactly how it works in Mongo, but in JavaScript, you can't compare two `Date` objects directly for equality as they are both different objects with the same value, so you may come across that problem as well. [See this post for an example on how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428327/checking-if-two-dates-have-the-same-date-info)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

I change the "select" line of the query by :
`.select({ sales: { $elemMatch: {"date": new Date("2013-12")} }});`

I tested it with different dates and it worked perfectly.
Thank you for your answer and your explanations :)

Comment: PS: I think you're still going to have issues with your date object as that will probably just create the same object as `new Date("2013-12-01")`. Might want to try comparing `$gt` the last day of the last month and `$lt` the first day in the next month.