# Do not count given holidays or weekends between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have included given code in my js file

```
$( '.dateDisable' ).change(function() {
    calculateDays();
});

function calculateDays() {
  var first = new Date( $( '#start_date' ).val() ),
    last = new Date( $( '#end_date' ).val() ),
    daysDiff = leaveCalculation( first,last);  
}

function leaveCalculation( d1, d2 ) {
  alert(gon.holiday) // 2015-08-28,2015-09-25,2016-08-31,2016-08-07,2015-08-13,2016-08-29,2016-01-07,2015-09-08
  var weeks, dateDiff, weekDay1, weekDay2;
  if ( d2 < d1 ) return -1;
  weekDay1 = d1.getDay(),
    weekDay2 = d2.getDay();
  weeks = Math.floor( ( d2.getTime() - d1.getTime() ) / 604800000 );
  if ( weekDay1 <= weekDay2 )
    dateDiff = ( weeks * 5 ) + ( weekDay2 - weekDay1 );
  else
    dateDiff = ( ( weeks + 1 ) * 5 ) - ( weekDay1 - weekDay2 );
  return ( dateDiff + 1 );
}
```

I want to calculate days.

If I have selected date "**27 August, 2015**" - "**31 August, 2015**" 
it will calculate daysDiff = 3 but I want to take out daysDiff as if there is holiday on 28-08-2015 as I am fetching holiday disable dates in `gon.holiday`.
In my case that would be

> 2015-08-28,2015-09-25,2016-08-31,2016-08-07,2015-08-13,2016-08-29,2016-01-07,2015-09-08

So if I have selected dates "**27 August, 2015**" - "**31 August, 2015**" then it will give me daysDiff as 2 because 28, 29 ,30 are already holiday.  I want to exclude weekend also

How would I do that?

Comment: Is `gon.holiday` an array or a plain string?

Comment: @dinshaw raje : what are **dDate2** and **dDate1** ? by the way you can compare by using loop with holidays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428327/checking-if-two-dates-have-the-same-date-info and then subract them from **diffDays**

Comment: its not an array it fetches simply like this 2015-08-28,2015-09-25,2016-08-31,2016-08-07,2015-08-13,2016-08-29,2016-01-07,2015-09-08

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```js
var gon = {};
gon["holiday"] = "2015-08-28,2015-09-25,2016-08-31,2016-08-07,2015-08-13,2016-08-29,2016-01-07,2015-09-08".split(",");

// 2 helper functions - moment.js is 35K minified so overkill in my opinion
function pad(num) { return ("0" + num).slice(-2); }
function formatDate(date) { var d = new Date(date), dArr = [d.getFullYear(), pad(d.getMonth() + 1), pad(d.getDate())];return dArr.join('-');}

function calculateDays(first,last) {
  var aDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  daysDiff = parseInt((last.getTime()-first.getTime())/aDay,10)+1;

  if (daysDiff>0) {  
    for (var i = first.getTime(), lst = last.getTime(); i <= lst; i += aDay) {
      var d = new Date(i);
      if (d.getDay() == 6 || d.getDay() == 0 // weekend
      || gon.holiday.indexOf(formatDate(d)) != -1) {
          daysDiff--;
      }
    }
  }
  return daysDiff;
}

// ONLY using jQuery here because OP already used it. I use 1.11 so IE8+

$(function() {
    var days = calculateDays(new Date($('#start_date').val()),
                             new Date($('#end_date').val()));
    if (days <= 0) {
      alert("Please enter an end date after the begin date");
    }
    else {
      alert(days +" working days found");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="start_date" value="27 August, 2015" />
<input id="end_date" value="31 August, 2015" />
```

Comment: I want to exclude weekend as well

Comment: Please see update. I replaced your leave calculation

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented rather easily with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```js
var startString = "2015-01-01";
var endString = "2015-02-20";
var holidaysString = "2015-01-03, 2015-01-15, 2015-02-05, 2015-03-01";

var start = moment(startString);
var end = moment(endString);
var holidays = holidaysString.split(',').map(function(str) {
  return moment(str);
});

var getDuration = function getDuration(start, end, holidays) {
  var overlappingDays = holidays.reduce(function(count, holiday) {
    return count + ~~(holiday.isAfter(start) && holiday.isBefore(end));
  }, 0);
  var diff = end.diff(start, 'days');
  return diff - overlappingDays;
};

output.innerHTML = getDuration(start, end, holidays);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<span id="output"></span> days.
```

Comment: Its not working as per my requirement I if I have dates between "27 August, 2015" - "31 August, 2015" then the no of days differ is 5 but I dont want to count sat and sun so it remains 3 but if there is some other holiday on 28 aug i.e on friday then it will not count holiday and output I want is 2  .

Comment: @dinshawraje If you wanted to exclude weekends as well, you should've started by writing that down in your question.

Comment: I have mentioned in my code that I am fetching days and then subtracting them

Comment: I would not call your code easy, readable or very understandable for beginners

Comment: @mplungjan What exactly are you having a hard time with? Using standard array methods or understanding a bitwise not?

Comment: I can read your code, but adding moment and ~~ and map and reduce and calling it easy?

Comment: @mplungjan Both map and reduce are standard array methods that are a core part of the language. Moment is the most commonly used Javascript date-time library. I don't see you making a point.

Comment: My point is to help a beginner. Map, reduce are standard (but quite new and unsupported in some browsers), ~~ are not standard usage but "clever". Moment.js is 35K unnecessary code in this case my opinion. Obviously others disagree since I got voted down and you got voted up

Comment: @mplungjan To be fair, you used jQuery, 82K of _"unnecessary code"_, just to get text from inputs for a small example so you're really building a straw-man argument here. Both map and reduce are supported by IE9+, the same browser support you get when using jQuery 2.x, just so you know.

Comment: Nope. OP already used that. My main code does not need jQuery and I use 1.11 in my snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the days between the days

Then split the string of dates that are coming in at `gon.holiday` into an array

Then loop through this array subtracting days if they are between the two dates

```js
function calculateDays(){
 var first = new Date( '27 August, 2015'),
    last = new Date('31 August, 2015'),
    daysDiff = leaveCalculation( first,last);
}
function leaveCalculation( d1, d2 ) {
  var holidayArr = [];
  var holiday = gon.holiday; //"2015-08-28,2015-09-25,2016-08-31,2016-08-07,2015-08-13,2016-08-29,2016-01-07,2015-09-08";
  if ( d2 < d1 ) return -1;
    
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    var difDays = Math.round(Math.abs((d1.getTime() - d2.getTime())/(oneDay))); //find the number of days between the two dates
    var holidayArr = holiday.split(','); //split at ,
    for(var i=0; i<holidayArr.length;i++){ //loop through array
     if(new Date(holidayArr[i]) <= d2 && new Date(holidayArr[i]) >= d1){ //check if two dates are between the given dates
            difDays-=1;
        }
    }
  return difDays;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```