# array.filter not returning array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to search through an large array of data using a date column to return the array of the accounts that have the date I need.  I can't get the array to populate with any data.  What am I missing?

```
var accounts = accountInfo.getRange('A2:AJ').getValues();
var maxRow = accountInfo.getMaxRows();
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var todayPlus5 = addDays(today, 5);

function reviewPriorityFilter(){
  var filtered = accounts.filter(rowNumber2);
  accounts = filtered;
  Logger.log(filtered);
}

function rowNumber2(value){
  var fix = new Date(value[15]);
  fix.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  return fix === todayPlus5;
}

function addDays(date, days){
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: what _is_ array.filter returning? What does the variable `accounts` contain? Please make sure you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried calling the `rowNumber2` function? => `accounts.filter(rowNumber2());`

Comment: @Davion That would be a boolean; `filter` takes a function. `rowNumber2` itself should be passed.

Comment: `var filtered = (function () { return accounts.filter(rowNumber2); })();`

Comment: @Davion - Is that a joke? What is the IIFE supposed to do there?

Comment: Where do you actually call `reviewPriorityFilter()` ? The use of closing over the `accounts` variable is likely a culprit here.

Comment: You also can't use `===` with date objects. A new object will never `===` a different new object.

Comment: @nnnnnn No, I forgot that `filter` returns a new array, thought he made a mistake by not returning the array. My bad.

Comment: @Hamms it is returning an empty array.

Comment: @AndyRay it doesn't get called yet.  I'm trying to set up a series of filters to help retrieve specific accounts for my team members to review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `===` to compare new object instances. Two objects created with `new` will never `===` each other, even if they have the same "values", like the same internal date. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428327/checking-if-two-dates-have-the-same-date-info) shows the proper way to check for exact date matching:

```
date1.getTime() === date2.getTime()
```

So your `rowNumber2` filter should return something more like:

```
return fix.getTime() === todayPlus5.getTime();
```

Keep in mind this will only work if the times are *exactly* matching. If the filter is still showing an empty value, log both dates to see if they truly hold the exact same time.