# Lock a sheet when date in column > 24 hours: Google Sheets - Scripteditor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, locking

In order to prevent data loss caused by other contributors, I'd like to lock an entire sheet for all data < today.

It needs to be possible to do input and make changes for entries today.

An simple example of the master file : [EXAMPLE - LOCK < TODAY](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FQK4T5vlB-I2r0tkGq-CIeCyZESJOVdPHUTAJ10-t5U/edit#gid=0)

So, each row will lock for others when the date in column A < today.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811562/automatically-locking-a-range-column-as-each-date-passes-in-google-sheets)  brought me closer but I'm having difficulties with

> var range = ss.getRange('1:1').getValues()[0];

which gives me an error on line 31: "TYPE-ERROR: can't find function getFullYear in object..."

Open to any other idea/code.

Thank you in advance for helping me out!

Qni

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

**Protect Sheet except for today's rows**

I took the code you linked to from [pkowalczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43828395/7215091) and modified it to protect entire sheet except for the row that is for today.  Much of this code is also available in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setUnprotectedRanges(Range)).

```
//https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setUnprotectedRanges(Range)
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/43828395/7215091
function unlockTodaysRowFromSheetProtection() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('ProtectRows');
  var protection=sh.protect().setDescription('Protected Sheet');
  protection.getRange().setBackground('#ffffff');
  var rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  var todayRow = null;
  for (var i=0; i<vA.length; i++) {       
    if (today.isSameDateAs(vA[i][0])) {
      todayRow = i;
      break;
    }
  } 

  var rangeToUnProtect = sh.getRange(todayRow + 2,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([rangeToUnProtect]);
  protection.getRange().setBackground('#ffff00');//highlight protected range
  rangeToUnProtect.setBackground('#00ffff');//highlight unprotected range
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);  
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
  protection.addEditor('email@gmail.com'); // second person with edit permissions
}
```

This section came from [Incidently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4428396/2351523) and you can refer to it for more explanation.  The 'this' refers to today in the code and it just compares year,month and day.

```
/*
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4428396/2351523
*/
Date.prototype.isSameDateAs = function(pDate) {
  return (
    this.getFullYear() === pDate.getFullYear() &&
    this.getMonth() === pDate.getMonth() &&
    this.getDate() === pDate.getDate()
  );
}
```

> > This was an interesting question as I've not used protection very much. I found it handy to have the Protected Sheets and Ranges sidebar up while running the code. I highlighted the protected and unprotected ranges just to be clear what they are.

**Trying to unProtect more than one row**

This should help. It collects all of the ranges to unprotect in an array and unprotects all at one time.

```
function unprotectTodaysRowsFromSheetProtection() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('ProtectRows');
  var protection=sh.protect().setDescription('Protected Sheet');
  protection.getRange().setBackground('#ffffff');
  var rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  var uprgA=[];
  for (var i=0; i<vA.length; i++) {       
    if (today.isSameDateAs(vA[i][0])) {
      uprgA.push(sh.getRange(i + 2,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()))
    }
  } 
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(uprgA);
  protection.getRange().setBackground('#ffff00');
  for(var i=0;i<uprgA.length;i++){
    uprgA[i].setBackground('#00ffff');
  }
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);  
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
  protection.addEditor('email@gmail.com'); // second person with edit permissions
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper. Thank you for your feedback. I assume these are two different options. However, for both of them I receive a TypeError: Can't call null method protect. (line 4, file 'Code'). There is something with the **sh.protect().setDescription('Protected Sheet')**