# Comparing two dates in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to compare two dates using this code

```
  let dob=new Date(this.dob);  
  if(birthDate.getDate()==new Date("1990-01-01").getDate())
  {
    console.log('date is equal');
  }
  else 
  {
    console.log('date is not equal');
  }
```

but it shows date is equal when i have `2022-08-01` this date in `birthDate` variable.
Any solution Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if two Dates have the same date info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428327/checking-if-two-dates-have-the-same-date-info)

Answer (score 3):

The `getDate` method of `Date` returns the day of the date (in both cases you gave as an exampel, this is `01`). To compare between dates, you can use the `getTime` method (returns the number of milliseconds passed since Jan 1st, 1970)

[getDate documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Answer (score 0):

> you can use momentjs like this

```js
var bool2 = moment('2019-10-20').isSame('2019-10-20'); //true
console.log(bool2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```